# What criteria should I use for determining whether or not to terminate a daemon (to restart it later)?

Tags: unix, forking, cgi

Should a daemon, forked from a CGI script (whenever the CGI script is called and the daemon is not yet running), hang running (most of the time just waiting for a connection) all time, or should it be terminated as soon as there is no more data to process (to be restarted by the next CGI call)? (The process is a Perl script.)

This happens on FreeBSD.

The details of what I am going to implement are available at [Writing a daemon behind CGI: WebSocket or long polling](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/324876/45576) question.

Comment: Do you have any criteria for evaluating your decision?  Are you running out of memory, for example?

Comment: @RobertHarvey No, I asked for such a criteria. I think our server has plenty of memory

Comment: I edited the title of your post to more correctly reflect the question that I think you're asking.  Feel free to re-edit or roll back if that's not your actual question.

Comment: Please improve your question by explaining what your CGI is doing, and what is the daemon doing. Give some motivation and context (so **edit your question**)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Done

Comment: A reason to terminate the script when there is no data to process right now is that it simplifies debugging as I do not need to kill the script after every change in its cod

Comment: As soon as it starts, there are no yet any connections. So it could exit immediately and thus does not work at all, if it exited on the event of no connections. This is an argument to keep it running persistently.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your situation is a good candidate for (at least) [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI), or perhaps making some dedicated HTTP server (perhaps using some HTTP server library like [libonion](https://www.coralbits.com/libonion/)) that your main web server would use as "proxy" for some selected requests or URLs.

There is also the issue about what kind of state should the daemon keep from one CGI request to the next one.

Intuitively, you could use as criteria to stop your daemon after a few minutes (real-time) of inactivity.

<sup>(You definitely should give more details and motivations)</sup>

Comment: See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/324876/45576 for more details and motivations